# Создание OCR-программы для распознавания бланков регистрации

Tags: c#, opencv, распознавание-символов

Передо мной стала задача разработать приложение для распознавания отсканированных бланков регистрации на подобии тех, что используются в ЕГЭ.

Конечно же, в первую очередь я сказал начальству, что нам нужен [ABBY FlexiCapture](http://www.abbyy.ru/flexicapture/), но денег в бюджете пока нет.

Я преимущественно программирую в `.NET/C#`. Если надо, то могу использовать `C++` или `Python`.

Вот сам бланк регистрации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо в приложении указать участок, где указан код региона и из этих двух клеток распознать число (20).

Подскажите в какую сторону «копать»? Google-поиск выдает преимущественно `OpenCV`, `Tesseract`, `PyTesser`. Конкретно по .NET особо ничего нет. Но как я уже говорил `C++/Python` тоже могу использовать.

Если брать конкретно по [PyTesser](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/):

```
from pytesser import
image = Image.open('fnord.tif')
print image_to_string(image)
```

то не из самого примера и не в самой документации не сказано, как указать конкретно участок распознавания. Как я предполагаю, наверное нужно указать какие-то координаты или как?

Если смотреть в сторону `OpenCV` и на вооружение взять `C++`, то это (OpenCV) целый кладезь знаний. Тут мысли разбегаются и не знаешь куда податься - cтолько всего «всякого». Может посоветуете какую-нибудь книжку или статью, где будет говориться о конкретном разделе `OpenCV` который нужен мне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша задача одновременно и простая, и сложная. С одной стороны, имеется набор образцов, которым должен следовать человек, заполняя бланк регистрации. Каждое поле имеет контрастный белый цвет по сравнению с цветом окружения. Но с другой стороны, люди не все и не всегда следуют правилам, а также в процессе внесения данных могут запросто выйти за пределы границ, что отчётливо видно в примере с цифрой "0".

`Tesseract` натравлять на эту задачу бесполезно, только если заранее не озаботиться его обучением на шрифт бланка. Если заложенный в библиотеке шрифт позволит достаточно уверенно распознать, например, единицу и пятёрку, то с четвёркой и семёркой однозначно возникнут проблемы. Просто в шрифте, на который по умолчанию обучен `tesseract` (что для английского, что для русского языков), обозначенные цифры имеют отличающееся начертание, что в конечном итоге приведёт к большому проценту неверно распознанных символов.

Лично я бы посоветовал использовать `OpenCV` и какой-нибудь алгоритм машинного обучения, например, `SVM`. Но прежде необходимо позаботиться об обучающих материалах, что как правило заготавливаются в процессе ручного труда. Потребуется что-то вроде того, что представлено на изображении ниже и, разумеется, для каждого символа в отдельности. В идеале, обучающий набор должен состоять из предварительно нарезанных символов непосредственно с бланков регистрации, которые были ранее заполнены, например, при сдаче экзамена в прошлом году.

[image]

Что касаемо непосредственно детекции полей, содержащих символы, то здесь не должно быть особой сложности. Всё, что нужно сделать, это привести изображение к бинарному виду, а далее воспользоваться поиском контуров при помощи той же `findContours()` из состава `OpenCV`.

Если возникнет проблема на конкретном этапе реализации задачи, то задайте по нему отдельный вопрос, поскольку в целом тема довольно обширна и раскрытие её в деталях будет претендовать на весьма добротную статью.